# Dynamic , Using a Case Statement in a Where Clause in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-connector

I am stucked at a dynamic where clause inside case statement.

**WHAT I NEED**

When i used this

```
SELECT col1,col2,col3
FROM Recharge r INNER join ft f ON f.date=r.date
WHERE f.Date LIKE 
CASE WHEN f.Date  BETWEEN (last_day(curdate() - interval 1 month) + interval 1 day) AND last_day(curdate())  
                  THEN f.Date  ELSE f.date between subdate(curdate(),interval 1 month) and (last_day(curdate() - interval 1 month)) END
ORDER BY f.id desc;
```

The syntax is wrong but when instead it '2022-04%'.

```
SELECT col1,col2,col3

FROM Recharge r INNER join ft f ON f.date=r.date
WHERE f.Date LIKE 
CASE WHEN f.Date  BETWEEN (last_day(curdate() - interval 1 month) + interval 1 day) AND last_day(curdate())  
                  THEN f.Date  ELSE '2022-04%' END
ORDER BY f.id desc;
```

It is correct  but i want to change dynamically.how can i do it.
I mean that
when i run the query include date of 1-4-2022 to 30-4-2022.
The snapshot my database include  data of yesterday in the begin of month i have the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A case statement can only return a value and not a range. If I understand rightly it is only the start date which changes so we only need to decide the start date in the case statement. If the end date also changes we will need a second case statement.
However it looks like a simple test will return the same results

```
SELECT col1,col2,col3
FROM Recharge r INNER join ft f ON f.date=r.date
WHERE f.Date BETWEEN
curdate() - interval 1 month
  AND
last_day(curdate())
ORDER BY f.id desc;
```

Re-reading your explanation I think that you really want

```
SELECT col1,col2,col3
FROM Recharge r INNER join ft f ON f.date=r.date
WHERE month(f.date) = month(curdate() - interval 1 day)
AND year(f.date) = year(curdate() - interval 1 day )
ORDER BY f.id desc;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b3da19603f17cf27fd367f22bd02c460)*

Comment: Thank you a lot for your efforts.you safe me .i use "IF" for this reason:
WHERE 
IF(f.Date  BETWEEN (last_day(curdate() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND last_day(curdate()) ,f.Date,
f.Date BETWEEN subdate(curdate(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND (last_day(curdate() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)))
     ORDER BY f.id DESC;

Comment: Glad you found the solution. Please upvote if the answer helped.

Comment: actually i have a bit problem but close to 'solve it',i am trying another way for solving issue... thank you again.

Comment: please see modified second query

Comment: thank you a lot Kendle your query.really it is a great and i think it is correct.
SELECT col1,col2,col3
FROM Recharge r INNER join ft f ON f.date=r.date
WHERE month(f.date) = month(curdate() - interval 1 day)
AND year(f.date) = year(curdate() - interval 1 day )
ORDER BY f.id desc;
so i have another idea i am using by programming language for solving the issue.

Comment: Glad to help have a good evening